# Error in Mysqldump import

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

A client gave me his mysqldump (via phpmyadmin) to be imported on our servers, but I get the following error on the import:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE `agvGalerias` ADD CONSTRAINT `agvGalerias_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idAutor' at line 3
```

The line that runs the error is:

```
ALTER TABLE `agvGalerias`
ADD CONSTRAINT `agvGalerias_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idAutor`) REFERENCES `agvUsuarios`            (`idUsuario`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ALTER TABLE `agvGalerias`
ADD CONSTRAINT `agvGalerias_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idAutor`) REFERENCES `agvUsuarios` (`idUsuario`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,  ADD CONSTRAINT `agvGalerias_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`idModificador`) REFERENCES `agvUsuarios` (`idUsuario`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Client side:

```
phpMyAdmin version: 2.9.0
Mysql version: 5.1.38
```

My side:

```
Mysql version: 5.1.69
```

I would appreciate some help or orientation to fix this.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this export bug in this old phpMyAdmin version (2.9.0), but the bug is no longer present in the currently stable 4.0.8 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the SQL that you provided, my guess is that the syntax error is on that second ALTER TABLE part.  If you notice, the first ALTER TABLE statement has a comma at the end of it, not a semicolon.  This makes the second statement invalid syntax as the first is not terminated properly.

Comment: That's it. The phpmyadmin dump had lots of duplicate entries. I remove them by hand and now it works. Thanks.